# Twilio VideoView и Android SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, камера

Я изучаю Андроид по урокам и хочу подключить Twilio в урок [посвященный камере](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/264-urok-132-kamera-vyvod-izobrazhenija-na-ekran-obrabotka-povorota.html)
В том уроке используется SurfaceView, а в Twilio некий свой VideoView, как описано [здесь](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/getting-started#video-api-overview) 
Ну то есть в классическом Андроиде мы видим 
`sv = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);`
А в Twilio -  `VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);`

Как бы заставить Twilio  работать с SurfaceView?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать. Какая цель в заставлении твиллио работать с surfaceview ? 
Зашарить свою камеру собеседнику можно так: ([ссылка на документацию](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/android-v3-configuring-audio-video-input-and-output-devices))

```
// Share your camera
CameraCapturer cameraCapturer = new CameraCapturer(context, CameraSource.FRONT_CAMERA);
LocalVideoTrack localVideoTrack = LocalVideoTrack.create(context, true, cameraCapturer);

// Render camera to a view
VideoView primaryVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.local_video);

// Mirror front camera
primaryVideoView.setMirror(true);

// Render camera to view
localVideoTrack.addRenderer(primaryVideoView);

// Switch the camera source
CameraSource cameraSource = cameraCapturer.getCameraSource();
cameraCapturer.switchCamera();
primaryVideoView.setMirror(cameraSource == CameraSource.BACK_CAMERA);
```

Вывести изображение от собеседника можно как сделано [в этом примере](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/building-video-applications-on-android.html). Для этого надо использовать VideoViewRenderer. В документации сказано, что

> A VideoViewRenderer receives frames from a local or remote video track
>   and renders the frames to a provided view

Надеюсь, эта информация будет полезна вам. Happy coding!

[image: twilio]

Comment: Ну, допустим я захочу "обогатить" этот пример какими-нибудь графическими спецэффектами, взяв готовую библиотеку с GitHub; вполне вероятно, что та библиотека будет использовать стандартный SurfaceView. Если заранее ясно что подружить их не получится, то я не буду тратить время на изучение Twilio и поищу что-нибудь похожее, но использущее SurfaceView - например, nextcloud/talk-android.
(P.S. не пинайте если глупость сказал)

Comment: @Dmbor думаю, в данном случае Твиллио это не совсем то, что вы ищите. Это платный фреймворк, с достаточным (по их мнению) функционалом. Кстати, вы можете написать им в поддержку. Они обычно достаточно оперативно отвечают.

Для бесплатных проектов или просто для обучения лучше взять что-нибудь другое.

Comment: То есть, добавить Face recognition с того же GitHub (например, https://github.com/div1090/Face-Recognition-on-Android)  в Twilio не удастся? 
Что ж, поищем что-нибудь другое тогда. А в поддержку напишу, спасибо.